# make all error while installing caffe with matlab

Tags: protocol-buffers, caffe, matcaffe

I am trying to install caffe with cpu support and matcaffe wrapper. My system config: **Ubuntu -16.04, opencv 2.4.9, gcc-4.9, g++-4.9, Matlab2017b**
I am unable to figure out the error I have seen many possible options available and patched the solution. I have included my Makefile.config as Makefile with the error:

```
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/caffe.bin
.build_release/tools/caffe.o: In function `train()':
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x33ca): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::StringTypeHandlerBase::New()'
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x4267): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::StringTypeHandlerBase::New()'
.build_release/tools/caffe.o: In function `std::string* google::MakeCheckOpString<unsigned long, int>(unsigned long const&, int const&, char const*)':
caffe.cpp:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringImiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringImiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x50): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString()'
.build_release/tools/caffe.o: In function `main':
caffe.cpp:(.text.startup+0x53): undefined reference to `google::SetVersionString(std::string const&)'
caffe.cpp:(.text.startup+0x86): undefined reference to `google::SetUsageMessage(std::string const&)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::InitializationErrorString() const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::string const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteStringWithSizeToArray(std::string const&, unsigned char*)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::ReadString(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*, std::string*)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::GetTypeName() const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::DebugString() const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::MessageLite::ParseFromString(std::string const&)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::NameOfEnum(google::protobuf::EnumDescriptor const*, int)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::FindFileByName(std::string const&) const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::ReadBytes(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*, std::string*)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::StringTypeHandlerBase::Delete(std::string*)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::MessageFactory::InternalRegisterGeneratedFile(char const*, void (*)(std::string const&))'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `leveldb::DB::Open(leveldb::Options const&, std::string const&, leveldb::DB**)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::imencode(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteBytesMaybeAliased(int, std::string const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `leveldb::Status::ToString() const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteString(int, std::string const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:626: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/caffe.bin' failed
make: *** [.build_release/tools/caffe.bin] Error 1
```

Makefile (My guess is it's some sort of linking error but I am unable to figure it out):

```html
## Refer to http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html
# Contributions simplifying and improving our build system are welcome!

# cuDNN acceleration switch (uncomment to build with cuDNN).
# USE_CUDNN := 1

# CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support).
CPU_ONLY := 1

# uncomment to disable IO dependencies and corresponding data layers
# USE_OPENCV := 0
# USE_LEVELDB := 0
# USE_LMDB := 0

# uncomment to allow MDB_NOLOCK when reading LMDB files (only if necessary)
# You should not set this flag if you will be reading LMDBs with any
# possibility of simultaneous read and write
# ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK := 1

# Uncomment if you're using OpenCV 3
# OPENCV_VERSION := 3

# To customize your choice of compiler, uncomment and set the following.
# N.B. the default for Linux is g++ and the default for OSX is clang++
# CUSTOM_CXX := g++

# CUDA directory contains bin/ and lib/ directories that we need.
# CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda
# On Ubuntu 14.04, if cuda tools are installed via
# "sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit" then use this instead:
# CUDA_DIR := /usr

# CUDA architecture setting: going with all of them.
# For CUDA < 6.0, comment the *_50 through *_61 lines for compatibility.
# For CUDA < 8.0, comment the *_60 and *_61 lines for compatibility.
# For CUDA >= 9.0, comment the *_20 and *_21 lines for compatibility.
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
  -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
  -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
  -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 \
  -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 \
  -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 \
  -gencode arch=compute_61,code=compute_61

# BLAS choice:
# atlas for ATLAS (default)
# mkl for MKL
# open for OpenBlas
BLAS := atlas
# Custom (MKL/ATLAS/OpenBLAS) include and lib directories.
# Leave commented to accept the defaults for your choice of BLAS
# (which should work)!
# BLAS_INCLUDE := /path/to/your/blas
# BLAS_LIB := /path/to/your/blas

# Homebrew puts openblas in a directory that is not on the standard search path
# BLAS_INCLUDE := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/include
# BLAS_LIB := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/lib

# This is required only if you will compile the matlab interface.
# MATLAB directory should contain the mex binary in /bin.
 MATLAB_DIR := /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b
 MATLAB_INCLUDE := /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/toolbox/distcomp/gpu/extern/include
 # /usr/local
# MATLAB_DIR := /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app

# NOTE: this is required only if you will compile the python interface.
# We need to be able to find Python.h and numpy/arrayobject.h.
PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python2.7 \
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
# Anaconda Python distribution is quite popular. Include path:
# Verify anaconda location, sometimes it's in root.
# ANACONDA_HOME := $(HOME)/anaconda
# PYTHON_INCLUDE := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include \
  # $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include/python2.7 \
  # $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include

# Uncomment to use Python 3 (default is Python 2)
# PYTHON_LIBRARIES := boost_python3 python3.5m
# PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python3.5m \
#                 /usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include

# We need to be able to find libpythonX.X.so or .dylib.
PYTHON_LIB := /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
# PYTHON_LIB := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib

# Homebrew installs numpy in a non standard path (keg only)
# PYTHON_INCLUDE += $(dir $(shell python -c 'import numpy.core; print(numpy.core.__file__)'))/include
# PYTHON_LIB += $(shell brew --prefix numpy)/lib


# Uncomment to support layers written in Python (will link against Python libs)
WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1

# Whatever else you find you need goes here.
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial/ $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) $(MATLAB_INCLUDE) 
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial

# If Homebrew is installed at a non standard location (for example your home directory) and you use it for general dependencies
# INCLUDE_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/include
# LIBRARY_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/lib

# NCCL acceleration switch (uncomment to build with NCCL)
# https://github.com/NVIDIA/nccl (last tested version: v1.2.3-1+cuda8.0)
# USE_NCCL := 1

# Uncomment to use `pkg-config` to specify OpenCV library paths.
# (Usually not necessary -- OpenCV libraries are normally installed in one of the above $LIBRARY_DIRS.)
# USE_PKG_CONFIG := 1

# N.B. both build and distribute dirs are cleared on `make clean`
BUILD_DIR := build
DISTRIBUTE_DIR := distribute

# Uncomment for debugging. Does not work on OSX due to https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/171
# DEBUG := 1

# The ID of the GPU that 'make runtest' will use to run unit tests.
TEST_GPUID := 0

# enable pretty build (comment to see full commands)
Q ?= @
```

Comment: I don't have a specific solution.  However, when I tripped over these problems, the errors were due to lack of the proper library to link.  This came from two causes: (1) library not installed; (2) wrong library *version* earlier in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  Unfortunately, I don't recall how my IT support traced and fixed the problem for me -- it took someone who knew the OS library installation much better than my "sudo yum install" level of expertise.  :-)

Comment: I changed the compiler and it worked. But now there is an error in mattest.

Comment: Okay; let's take this to "answer space".

Comment: Hmmm ... "an error in mattest" suggests a new posting with different tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a specific solution. However, when I tripped over these problems, the errors were due to lack of the proper library to link. This came from two causes: (1) library not installed; (2) wrong library version earlier in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Unfortunately, I don't recall how my IT support traced and fixed the problem for me -- it took someone who knew the OS library installation much better than my "sudo yum install" level of expertise. :-)

You also commented that changing the compiler worked: another possibility, as a new compiler has a new load path.  Good work!

Comment: I have created a new issue [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076045/error-in-make-mattest-in-caffe], if you want to look into it. Thanks.