# Error in make mattest in caffe

Tags: matlab, caffe, matcaffe

I am able to compile matcaffe but I am unable to run **make mattest**.  My system config: Ubuntu -16.04, opencv 2.4.9, gcc-5, g++-5, Matlab2017b. 
Here's the crash report from matlab:

```
           Segmentation violation detected at Fri Mar  2 12:37:16 2018
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled - No sandbox or build area path
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Graphics Driver: Unknown software 
  Current Visual      : None
  Default Encoding    : UTF-8
  Deployed            : false
  GNU C Library       : 2.23 stable
  Host Name           : saurabh-GL502VM
  MATLAB Architecture : glnxa64
  MATLAB Entitlement ID: 4851483
  MATLAB Root         : /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b
  MATLAB Version      : 9.3.0.713579 (R2017b)
  OpenGL              : software
  Operating System    : Linux 4.13.0-36-generic #40~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 16 23:25:58 UTC 2018 x86_64
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 94 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.8.0_121-b13 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : No active display

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 00007fae1974e700  RBX = 00007fae1974e6ff
  RCX = 00007fae1974f640  RDX = 00007fae1974e6ff
  RSP = 00007faf165e6420  RBP = 00007faf165e6470
  RSI = 00007faf165e6550  RDI = 00007faf165e6470

   R8 = 0000ff5c32e9dd3f   R9 = 0000000000000000
  R10 = 000000000000007b  R11 = 00007faf32ad49c0
  R12 = 00007faf165e6550  R13 = 00007fae1974f740
  R14 = 00007faf165e66c0  R15 = 00007faf165e71a8

  RIP = 00007faf32ad4a5b  EFL = 0000000000010206

   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007faf32ad4a5b /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0+00059995 _ZNK5boost10filesystem4path8filenameEv+00000155
[  1] 0x00007faf32ad5b36 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0+00064310 _ZNK5boost10filesystem4path9extensionEv+00000022
[  2] 0x00007faf32ad5c62 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0+00064610 _ZN5boost10filesystem4path17replace_extensionERKS1_+00000034
[  3] 0x00007fae70274928 /home/saurabh/caffe/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64+01100072
[  4] 0x00007fae70274d80 /home/saurabh/caffe/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64+01101184
[  5] 0x00007fae701a86b7 /home/saurabh/caffe/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64+00263863
[  6] 0x00007fae701a5a62 /home/saurabh/caffe/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64+00252514 mexFunction+00000169
[  7] 0x00007faf23e8c3c7                              bin/glnxa64/libmex.so+00172999 mexRunMexFile+00000439
[  8] 0x00007faf23e85c23                              bin/glnxa64/libmex.so+00146467
[  9] 0x00007faf23e86385                              bin/glnxa64/libmex.so+00148357
[ 10] 0x00007faf25bf7c83                   bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00830595 _ZN8Mfh_file16dispatch_fh_implEMS_FviPP11mxArray_tagiS2_EiS2_iS2_+00000947
[ 11] 0x00007faf25bf854e                   bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00832846 _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000030
[ 12] 0x00007faf2226390a                          bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+12519690
[ 13] 0x00007faf22264d9e                          bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+12524958
[ 14] 0x00007faf22325779                          bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+13313913
[ 15] 0x00007faf222caeb1                          bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+12943025
[ 16] 0x00007faf21bb2e50                          bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05504592
[ 17] 0x00007faf21bb50e4                          bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05513444
[ 18] 0x00007faf21bb18d1                          bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05499089
[ 19] 0x00007faf21bad861                          bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05482593
[ 20] 0x00007faf21badc89                          bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05483657
[ 21] 0x00007faf21bb1100                          bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05497088
[ 22] 0x00007faf21bb11cf                          bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05497295
[ 23] 0x00007faf21cb11d1                          bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+06545873
[ 24] 0x00007faf21cb3f53                          bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+06557523
[ 25] 0x00007faf221634ce                          bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+11470030
[ 26] 0x00007faf221288fa                          bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+11229434
[ 27] 0x00007faf22128e78                          bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+11230840
[ 28] 0x00007faf2212a6e2                          bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+11237090
[ 29] 0x00007faf221a024e                          bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+11719246
[ 30] 0x00007faf221a0702                          bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+11720450
[ 31] 0x00007faf254ee9a1                  bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02431393 _Z51inEvalCmdWithLocalReturnInDesiredWSAndPublishEventsRKSbIDsSt11char_traitsIDsESaIDsEEPibbP15inWorkSpace_tag+00000065
[ 32] 0x00007faf26a82823                            bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00694307 _ZNK3iqm18InternalEvalPlugin24inEvalCmdWithLocalReturnERKSbIDsSt11char_traitsIDsESaIDsEEP15inWorkSpace_tag+00000083
[ 33] 0x00007faf26a8417b                            bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00700795 _ZN3iqm18InternalEvalPlugin7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000123
[ 34] 0x00007faf260de40d                            bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00656397
[ 35] 0x00007faf26a758b8                            bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00641208
[ 36] 0x00007faf26a63db2                            bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00568754
[ 37] 0x00007faf240c177a                         bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00165754
[ 38] 0x00007faf240c91c3                         bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00197059
[ 39] 0x00007faf240c92db                         bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00197339
[ 40] 0x00007faf240c99b7                         bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00199095 _Z8mnParserv+00000647
[ 41] 0x00007faf260c6793                            bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00558995
[ 42] 0x00007faf260c892e                            bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00567598
[ 43] 0x00007faf260c9099                            bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00569497 _ZN5boost6detail17task_shared_stateINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvRKNS_8functionIFvvEEEENS2_5list1INS2_5valueIS6_EEEEEEvE6do_runEv+00000025
[ 44] 0x00007faf260c78b6                            bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00563382
[ 45] 0x00007faf26aab259                            bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00860761
[ 46] 0x00007faf26a97b6c                            bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00781164 _ZN5boost6detail8function21function_obj_invoker0ISt8functionIFNS_3anyEvEES4_E6invokeERNS1_15function_bufferE+00000028
[ 47] 0x00007faf26a9784c                            bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00780364 _ZN3iqm18PackagedTaskPlugin7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000428
[ 48] 0x00007faf26a758b8                            bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00641208
[ 49] 0x00007faf26a6353f                            bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00566591
[ 50] 0x00007faf26a65759                            bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00575321
[ 51] 0x00007faf34ac4aba                       bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+02702010
[ 52] 0x00007faf34ac606f                       bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+02707567
[ 53] 0x00007faf34ac681a                       bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+02709530 _Z25svWS_ProcessPendingEventsiib+00000186
[ 54] 0x00007faf260c6f0e                            bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00560910
[ 55] 0x00007faf260c72b4                            bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00561844
[ 56] 0x00007faf260b4c06                            bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00486406
[ 57] 0x00007faf339d66ba              /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+00030394
[ 58] 0x00007faf3370c41d                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+01078301 clone+00000109
[ 59] 0x0000000000000000                                   <unknown-module>+00000000


This error was detected while a MEX-file was running. If the MEX-file
is not an official MathWorks function, please examine its source code
for errors. Please consult the External Interfaces Guide for information
on debugging MEX-files.

If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.** This crash report has been saved to disk as /home/saurabh/matlab_crash_dump.18511-1 **


Warning: The following error was caught while executing 'caffe.Solver' class
destructor:
Error using caffe_
Usage: caffe_('delete_solver', hSolver)

Error in caffe.Solver/delete (line 40)
      caffe_('delete_solver', self.hSolver_self);

Error in caffe.Solver (line 17)
    function self = Solver(varargin)

Error in caffe.test.test_solver (line 22)
      self.solver = caffe.Solver(solver_file);

Error in caffe.run_tests (line 14)
  run(caffe.test.test_solver) ... 
> In caffe.Solver (line 17)
  In caffe.test.test_solver (line 22)
  In caffe.run_tests (line 14) 
Caught "std::exception" Exception message is:
FatalException
Caught MathWorks::System::FatalException
[Please exit and restart MATLAB]>>exit
```

I tried to change the Solver.m as given in https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/5588 but I ran into error given in https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/6270. Now what should I do? I am unable to understand the error.

Comment: Can you try the solution given in [PR#5642](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/5642)?

Comment: @Przemek I tried that solution, it didn't work. In fact, it was already correct in the source code. Check this out https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/6270